# For Sites 9.1, Custom resolver which covers both itemType Page and Component together in manifest.json

Tags: sites-9.1, custom-resolver

For Sites 9.1, I have written Custom resolver for doing an action when someone Un-publish page or component.

I am deploying using Add-on server. My package consists of .dll and manifest file.

Sharing manifest file content that takes care of page scenario(using itemType:

Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page) and Component scenario separately (using itemType:Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component) for Components.

However, I am not able to modify manifest.json correctly for both page and component itemType together.

**What would be the configuration update in manifest.json to cover both Page & Component?**

**manifest.json file content:**

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "id": "AssetUnpublish",
  "name": "AssetUnpublish",
  "author": "SDL developers",
  "description": "Custom Resolver",
  "minVersion": "0.0.0.0",
  "maxVersion": "15.0.0.0",
  "requireConfiguration": "No",
  "extensions": [
    {
      "type": "CMResolver",
      "name": "AssetUnpublish",
      "supportedVersions": "0.0.0.0",
      "properties": {
        "itemType": "Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page",
        "type": "CustomAssetResolver.MyResolver",
        "assemblyFileSource": "CustomAssetResolver.dll"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Mohan did you review the documentation -> https://docs.sdl.com/783502/694361/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/custom-resolver-extension

Comment: @Anand: There is not much on documentation to cover this scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`manifest.json` file allows multiple extensions, so you could add resolvers for both Component and Page as separate entries.

For example:

**manifest.json file with multiple extentions:**

```
        "extensions": [
           {
          "type": "CMResolver",
          "name": "AssetUnpublish",
          "supportedVersions": "0.0.0.0",
          "properties": {
            "itemType": "Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page",
            "type": "CustomAssetResolver.MyResolver",
            "assemblyFileSource": "CustomAssetResolver.dll"      
          },
          {
            "type": "CMResolver",
            "name": "ComponentPublishResolver",
            "supportedVersions": "0.0.0.0",
            "properties": {
              "itemType": "Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component",
              "type": "CustomAssetResolver.MyComponentPublishingResolver",
              "assemblyFileSource": "CustomAssetResolver.dll"
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Thank you @shahid .. I tried this option and it works well :)

Comment: @Mohan Happy to help, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

**Sharing working copy of my manifest.json with little modification** :

```
{
  "manifestVersion": "1.0",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "id": "AssetUnpublish",
  "name": "AssetUnpublish",
  "author": "SDL developers",
  "description": "Custom Resolver",
  "minVersion": "0.0.0.0",
  "maxVersion": "15.0.0.0",
  "requireConfiguration": "No",
  "extensions": [
    {
      "type": "CMResolver",
      "name": "AssetUnpublish",
      "supportedVersions": "0.0.0.0",
      "properties": {
        "itemType": "Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page",
        "type": "CustomAssetResolver.MyResolver",
        "assemblyFileSource": "CustomAssetResolver.dll"
      }
     },
      {
        "type": "CMResolver",
        "name": "ComponentPublishResolver",
        "supportedVersions": "0.0.0.0",
        "properties": {
          "itemType": "Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component",
          "type": "CustomAssetResolver.MyResolver",
          "assemblyFileSource": "CustomAssetResolver.dll"
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Good to see your full config, but please accept the @Shahid Eqamuddin answer.

Comment: @velu - Thanks for pointing out. Done :)